# ::before появляется неполностью

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть , к нижней части которого нужно добавить svg картинку, однако при добавлении её на left: 0;
bottom: -6px; (сама картинка высотой 6px), то она не появляется и добавляется вертикальный скрол.[image]
Вот примерно, что должно получится (оформление текста просто не доделал, с этим проблем нет)

P.S. графику не могу загрузить, можно чисто background-color закрасить

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: white;
}

body {
  min-width: 280px;
}

.container {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #3C4140;
}

header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -6px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header-brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header-brand span {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #85BD71;
}

.header-nav-bar {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.header-nav-bar:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Bouquet Pandora | TopFlowers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <h6 class="header-brand"><span>Top</span>Flowers</h6>

      <nav>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">Gifts</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">Roses</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">Baskets</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">About us</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">Contacts</a>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.nav -->
    </header>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> она не появляется и добавляется вертикальный скрол

Всему виной твой `overflow-x: hidden;`...

Если его отменить на "ключевых" элементах - все будет видно и без скрола.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: white;
}

body {
  min-width: 280px;
}

.container {
  width: 1100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 60px auto;
  /* добавил */
  overflow-x: visible;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #3C4140;
  /* добавил */
  overflow-x: visible;
}

header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -6px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.header-brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header-brand span {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #85BD71;
}

.header-nav-bar {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.header-nav-bar:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Bouquet Pandora | TopFlowers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <h6 class="header-brand"><span>Top</span>Flowers</h6>

      <nav>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">Gifts</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">Roses</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">Baskets</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">About us</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-nav-bar">Contacts</a>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.nav -->
    </header>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.